# $f(x) = \frac{x^2+2ax+b}{x^2+1}$. Prove that for $a \ne 0 $ there are two values such that $f'(x_1)$ and $f'(x_2)$ are parallel with axis x.

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(x) = \frac{x^2+2ax+b}{x^2+1}$

I don't really have any clue. Let me know if I get the question right: If $f'(x)$ is parallel to x axis that means that $f(x)$ is a first degree polynomial, is that right? So I need to prove that for $ a \ne 0 $ there are only 2 values for which $f(x)$ is a first degree polynomial. That means the $x^2$ can be cancelled for just two values of $x \in \mathbb R$.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this exercise.

Comment: This is not well-worded.  $f^{\prime}(x_1)$ is a number.  A number can't be parallel to a line.  Is the question whether the tangent lines to the curve of parallel to the $x$-axis?

Comment: Yes, that was the question, I couldn't fit it all in the title and shortened it this way. I need to prove that the tangent lines in $x_1$ and $x_2$ are parallel to x axis for just two values of $a \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a similar computation, I obtain
$$f'(x)=\frac{2(-ax^2+(1-b)x+a)}{(x^2+1)^2)},$$
and if $a\ne 0$, the numerator is a quadratic polynomial with   two real roots since its leading coefficient and its constant term have opposite signs.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: calculate $f'(x)$ and verify that the quadratic in the numerator has positive discriminant.

Comment: That is what I got.
$$f'(x)=\frac{(x^2+1)(2x+2a)-(x^2+2ax+b)(2x)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$  
The denominator is always positive. Then:  
$$f'(x)=\frac{2x^3+2ax^2+2x+2a-2x^3-4ax^2-2bx}{(x^2+1)^2}$$   
$$f'(x)=\frac{-2ax^2-2bx+2x+2a}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ 
$$f'(x)=\frac{-2a(x^2-1)-2x(b-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: That's right. So the quadratic in the numerator is $-2(ax^2+(b-1)x-a)$ & now verify that the disciminant is positive & so has two real roots.

Comment: The discriminant is $b^2-2b+1-4a^2$. I don't think there are any conditions on $a$ and $b$ apart from $a \ne 0$ so I don't know whether it is positive or not.    EDIT: It is actually $(b-1)^2+4a^2$ and it is indeed positive!

Comment: The discriminant will be $(b-1)^2 \color{red}{+} 4a^2$.